# Error when injecting a service in a HealthIndicator

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a `HSMService.java` class in which there is a `ping()` method allowing to ping a `HSM`.

```
package com.app.ddd.services;

import com.app.ddd.messages.EchoRequest;

public class HSMService implements HSMServiceI {

    private SynchronousEstablishedConnection connection;
    private String genericGroupName;

    public HSMService(EstablishedConnection connection, String genericGroupName) {
        this.connection = new SynchronousEstablishedConnection(connection);
        this.genericGroupName = genericGroupName;
    }

    @Override
    public void ping() {
        connection.submit(new EchoRequest());
    }
}
```

I want to inject this `HSMService` in a class that implements a `HealthIndicator` :

HSMHealthIndicator.java :

```
@Component
public class HSMHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Autowired
    private HSMService hsmService;

    private String host;
    private int port;

    private int checkHSMStatus() {

        //just to test
        if (hsmService == null)
            System.out.println("hsmService null");
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Health health() {

        if (checkHSMStatus() != 0) {
            return Health.down().withDetail("Error Code",   checkRKMSStatus()).build();
        }
        return Health.up().build();
    }

    public String getHost() {
       return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
       return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public HSMService getHSMService() {
       return hsmService;
    }

    public void setHSMService(HSMService hsmService) {
        this.hsmService= hsmService;
    }

 }
```

This class is used by a `HSMEndpoint.java` class which implements `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.Endpoint`

Excerpt of HSMEndpoint.java :

```
@Override
public String invoke() {

    HSMHealthIndicator h = new HSMHealthIndicator();
    h.setHost(this.getHost());
    h.setPort(this.getPort());
    Status s = h.health().getStatus();
    return "Status of the HSM : " + s.getCode();
}
```

Finally HSMEndpoint.java is configured by the class HSMEndpointConfiguration.java :

```
@Configuration
public class HSMEndpointConfiguration{

    @Bean
    //The value of hsm.host and the value of hsm.port are in application.properties
    public Endpoint getHSMEndpoint(@Value("${hsm.host}")String host, @Value("${hsm.port}")int port) {
        return new HSMEndpoint(host, port);
    }
 }
```

The root error is  :

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [com.app.ddd.services.HSMService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: where is the bean of type HSMService ?

Comment: Add the code for HSMService as well along with package names

Comment: in the package com.app.ddd.services

Comment: can you post the code to the question?

Comment: I have added the code of HSMService.java

Answer (score 1):

add the following line to HsmService class..

```
@Service("hsmService")
```

so it becomes..

```
@Service("hsmService")
public class HSMService implements HSMServiceI {
```

Comment: I still have errors :
Error creating bean with name 'hsmService' defined in...
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [com.app.ddd.services.EstablishedConnection]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}